# Can't recognize the series. Can somebody take a look?

Tags: binomial-theorem

I am solving a question as part of which I got the below mentioned series. I tried a lot but couldn't recognize this.

$$
^m C_m m^n -  {^m C_{m-1} (m - 1)^n} + \cdots \pm {^mC_1} 1^n
$$

I am sure it's expansion of some famous series.

Can somebody help?

Comment: @user2421978 Take care to the terms you are using.  1) it is not a series:  it is a **finite** sum 2) what you are looking for is certainly not an "**expansion**" ; it is a reduction: you are looking for a simpler expression, or even a closed form formulas

Answer (score 4):

If you define $(Df)(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$ then your expression is 
$$
(D^m f)(x)=\binom{m}{m} f(x+m)-\binom{m}{m-1}f(x+m-1)\pm…+(-1)^{m-1}\binom{m}1f(x+1)+(-1)^m\binom{m}{0}f(x+0)
$$ 
where $f(x) = x^n$ and evaluated at $x=0$, in total it is an $m$-th derivative approximated by an $m$-th order difference quotient of step size 1.

---

- If $f$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, then $D^mf$ is a polynomial of degree $n-m$ if that is non-negative, or else the zero polynomial.
- If $n<m$ and $f(x)=x^n$, then $(D^mf)(x)=0$.
- If $n=m$ and $f(x)=x^n$, then $(D^mf)(x)=m!$.

Answer (score 1):

We use the notation $\binom{m}{j}$  instead of $^mC_j$ and we also use the *coefficient extraction* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$ in a series. This way we can write e.g.
\begin{align*}
  n![z^n]e^{jz}=j^n
  \end{align*}

> We obtain  for   $m\geq 1$
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{j=1}^m\binom{m}{j}(-1)^{m-j}j^n
> &=\sum_{j=1}^m\binom{m}{j}(-1)^{m-j}n![z^n]e^{jz}\\
> &=n![z^n]\sum_{j=1}^m\binom{m}{j}\left(e^z\right)^j(-1)^{m-j}\\
> &=n![z^n]\left((e^z-1)^m-1\right)\\
> &=n![z^n]\left(\left(z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots\right)^m-1\right)\\
> &=\begin{cases}
> -1&\qquad n=0\\
> 0&\qquad 1\leq n < m\\
> m!&\qquad n=m\\
> n![z^n](e^z-1)^m&\qquad n\geq m
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}

Comment: (+1). Greetings on 2017. This sum appears frequently and the formal power series proof is best I think even better than complex integrals, which are not really needed here.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Thanks Marko and happy new year! :-)